# Creating subdomain on Debian

Tags: debian, virtualhost, subdomain

I have Debian server with a site running, I wanted to create sub-domain, so I created file in the sites-available dir. In the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName shop.domain.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript

    #php_flag register_globals off
    #php_flag safe_mode off
    #php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/shop"
    <Directory "/var/www/shop">
        AllowOverride None
        Allow from All
        Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    </Directory>        
</VirtualHost>
```

...then commands:

```
a2ensite filename
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

The sub-domain the link in sites-enabled was created, but the sub-domain don't exist ("Server not found").

I am not very experienced, so... Thanks!

Comment: Did you actually set the DNS up to point that subdomain at your server?

Comment: Like Tom says.  Easiest way to test it is to add shop.domain.com to your hosts file on your computer and point it to the IP of your server.

Comment: I think working on shared hosts made me inattentive...
Thank you!...

Answer (score 1):

If the VHost was just not configured the right way, you would see the default page of you web server (like you open 127.0.0.1 on your server. But “Server not found” means that DNS could not be resolved.